# Can a command be used to build a row in bNiceMatrix?

Tags: macros, arrays, nicematrix

I want to build a `bNiceMatrix` by storing rows in commands. Here's a mwe.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

This is the matrix I want.
\[
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax]
    w x y z;
    a b c d;
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
Something goes wrong when I try to store the second row in a command.

\newcommand{\MySecondRow}{a b c d}
\[
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax]
    w x y z;
    \MySecondRow ;
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem seems to be that `\MySecondRow` is processed within `bNiceMatrix` as a single token. Is this fixable?

Comment: Short answer: no. Unless the maintainer accepts a feature request.

Comment: I have uploaded on CTAN a new version of `nicematrix` (6.27 2024-02-13) with a new key `light-syntax-expanded` to address that situation.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Amazing!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version 6.27 (2024-02-13) of `nicematrix` has a new key `light-syntax-expanded` designed to address that situation. When that key is in force, the body of the environment is expanded (in the TeX sens: it's an expansion of type `e` of LaTeX3) before being split into rows (but after the extraction of a potential `\CodeAfer`).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

This is the matrix I want.
\[
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax]
    w x y z;
    a b c d;
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
With the key \verb|light-syntax-expanded|.

\newcommand{\MySecondRow}{a b c d}
\[
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax-expanded]
    w x y z;
    \MySecondRow ;
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: This is great! Could you elaborate on what would happen if you added some `\CodeAfter`? I'd test myself, but my system will take a little time to update to 6.27.

Comment: The `\CodeAfter` must be explicit: that means that it can't be ``inside'' a macro used in the body of the environment (for instance, it can't be in your macro `\MySecondRow`). I think it's not a severe restriction...

Comment: Ahh ok that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

While you can't use the `&` in the actual [light-syntax] environment, if you're willing to specify it in the command itself this worked for me:

```
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\MySecondRow}{a & b & c & d}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax]
    w  x  y  z;
   \MySecondRow
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

And produces

[image]

Comment: Any insights into why this works? I'm fairly dumbfounded!

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick It's most likely an implementation artifact (i.e. it just happens to work because of how the package is implemented internally), for all you know it might break for the next package version.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I am equally shocked — I thought our best shot would be something like \newcommand{\MySecondRow}{{a}{b}{c}{d}}, but this didn't work. Interestingly, it seems as though specifying this command reverts back to all standard syntax (give \newcommand{\MyThirdRow}{p\\q\\r\\s} a try and you'll see)... according to the manual: "when the option light-syntax is used, the whole content of the environment is loaded as a TeX
argument to be analyzed. The environment doesn’t behave in that case as a standard environment of LaTeX which
only put TeX commands before and after the content."